# Source Code in Bullet Lists with reStructuredText

Tags: python, documentation, restructuredtext

I am trying to include source code in bullet lists with reStructuredText; like this:

```
- List item 1 ::

  code sample...
  code sample...

- List item 2 ::

  code sample...
  code sample...
```

However, I get the following warning: 
`System Message: WARNING/2
Literal block expected; none found.`

The empty lines in the list are indented by a single space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You haven't indented enough.  Think of it this way.

```
- List item 1 
  ::

      code sample...
      code sample...

- List item 2 
  ::

      code sample...
      code sample...
```

Comment: Thank you! It is actually embarrassing that the fix is so simple. It seems I have to indent relative to the previous indentation level.

Comment: @ustun: "It seems I have to indent relative to the previous indentation level".  That's probably the most important rule of RST.

Comment: Thanks. But how much is enough? I can't find this in the documentation.

Comment: Any indentation--even just a single space--is sufficient.

Comment: It seems that html output has paragraphs more separated than without code